# Self referential association with attributes in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to replicate a relation where something can have many childrens, and many parents of itself with attributes.

```
item1 x2-> item2
      x3-> item3 x4-> item4 x2-> item1
                            x6-> item5
```

I'm not able to create the methods to retrieve the childrens, and the parents of the items.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Decomposition < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Item', foreign_key: 'children_omnicode'
 belongs_to :child, :class_name => 'Item', foreign_key: 'parent_omnicode'    
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :decompositions, foreign_key: :parent_omnicode
  has_many :children, :through => :decompositions, source: :child
  has_many :parents, :through => :decompositions, source: :parent
end
```

I'm able to create the children for the Item, but the .parent method returns the childrens also:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `Item` class association to `Decomposition` by creating two direct `has_many` associations:

```
class Decomposition < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Item', foreign_key: 'children_omnicode'
 belongs_to :child, :class_name => 'Item', foreign_key: 'parent_omnicode'    
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parent_decompositions, class_name: "Decomposition", foreign_key: :parent_omnicode
  has_many :child_decompositions, class_name: "Decomposition", foreign_key: :children_omnicode
  has_many :children, :through => :child_decompositions, source: :child
  has_many :parents, :through => :parent_decompositions, source: :parent
end
```

The way you have your code now, both the `:children` and `:parent` associations are referring to `Decompositions` where the `Item` is the parent. This solves that issue.

Comment: Worked except I needed to declare the class for the `parent_decompositions:
  has_many :parent_decompositions, class_name: 'Decomposition', foreign_key: :parent_omnicode`

Consider editing your answer for future researchers and thanks.

Comment: Thanks @JorgedelosSantos I updated the answer. There's always something to forget.